# Is there a way to enter an empty column in QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to create a panel of buttons that occupies only half of the window size. So my idea to this was (please feel free to suggest a better idea) to create 2 nested QHBox layouts that should ideally divive the entire window size into 2 and then in the 0th column I can add the 5 buttons that I need and leave the second column empty. However I have noticed that when I add a child layout that has no widgets it does not take up any space.

I have tried to add a spacer item to the second layout but the problem with that is that it requires width in terms of pixels which does not change whn the window is resized.

I have also tried the addStretch option but it reduces my buttons to minimum size and squeezes then to one corner leaving the rest of the space empty.

Can anyone please suggest me the optimal way to create a HBoxwidget that occupies only half of the window size

**EDIT:**
Adding a picture to clarify my requirement. I would like the 5 buttons shown on the bottom to only occupy the are marked by the red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Having a window with half of its size completely empty is a strange requirement. Are you trying to leave it empty because you're going to add something else there later? And what would that be?

Comment: It is just more aesthetically pleasing when compared to the other layouts on my window

Comment: You are saying that the buttons occupy half the window size, but then you say that there are other layouts in your window, which is in contrast to the above. Please try to clarify the current situation and possibly [edit] your post with an image of the current state and a mockup of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have added a picture that should hopefully clear up the requirements. You are right I do want the buttons to occupy just one half of the window size. The other layout, is just my attempt at trying to achieve this by adding a blank layout on the other half of the screen where I want nothing, but that did not work so you can disregard that bit entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement well, you should use the `stretch` parameter of these functions `QBoxLayout::addWidget(widget, stretch)` and `QBoxLayout::addLayout(layout, stretch)`. You should probably set it to 1 (if you do not specify stretch for other items) for both your sub-layouts/sub-widgets when adding them to parent layout. This way you can force them to occupy the same space.

Comment: I have tried this, however the problem with this technique is that if any one of the 2 layouts is empty (i.e. 0 widgets are added to them) that layout does not take up any space.

Ideally what i want really is one layout that can take half of my window space and another layout that is empty to take up the remaining half. (PS: it is not necessary that the remaining empty have of the space must have a layout )

Comment: In that case you can add a dummy `QWidget()` into that layout and set a stretch for it. `QWidget` will not be visible and will not have any function, it will be there just to force the layout stretch.